# OnCreate fires twice from onNewIntent

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle, android-deep-link

I am using deep link, launchMode="singleTask". If there is an instance of my activity everything works fine: only onNewIntent is called. But if there is no instance, firstly onCreate is called, then onNewIntent and again onCreate. That is why, the screen flickers. What is the problem? I removed all code, and only logged the events. But the same behavior is observed.

```html
<activity
            android:name="uz.avtobank.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
            android:theme="@style/SplashActivityTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden">

        <nav-graph android:value="@navigation/nav_graph_main" />

</activity>
            
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val host = NavHostFragment.create(R.navigation.nav_graph_main)
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, host)
            .setPrimaryNavigationFragment(host)
            .commit()

        logMessage("onCreate ${intent.action}")
    }

    @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
    override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent)
        logMessage("onNewIntent ${intent.action}")

        handleIntent(intent)
    }
    
    private fun handleIntent(intent: Intent) {
        if (intent.action != Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
            return

        try {
            findNavController(R.id.container).handleDeepLink(intent)
        } catch (e: IllegalStateException) {
        } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
        }

        setIntent(intent)
    }
```

The following appears on the log:
There is instance: onNewIntent
There is no instance: onCreate, onNewIntent, onCreate

The same happens evene if I remove handleIntent method.

Comment: share your code, otherwise its hard to tell